# Perfomance lost after parallelize C code with OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I need to parallelize a C code with OpenMP. I have done that like the following code. The performance of that code has dropped from 0.001XXXs to 1.XXX s so there are race conditions (bottleneck). Inside the code I have commented where are them (commented in MAYUS and no tabulated, for better visualization `//BOTTLENECK`). I do not know why this carer conditions.

The code is

```
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
#define MAX_ITER_NO_IMPR 10



void fail(const char * str) {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s", str);
    exit(-1);
}

/**
* calc_distance calculates the distance between a given point and a cluster
* @param int -dim: number of columns (variables) in the data set to be classified
* @param float * -: first arrray to calculate de distance
* @param float * -: Second array to calculate de distance 
* @return float: Euclidean distance of two vectors
*/
float calc_distance(int dim, float *restrict p1, float *restrict p2) {
    float distance_sq_sum = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:distance_sq_sum)     
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        distance_sq_sum += sqr(p1[i] - p2[i]);

    return distance_sq_sum;  
}

/**
* calc_all_distances computes the euclidean distances between centros ids and dataset points. 
* @param int -dim: number of columns (variables) in the data set to be classified
* @param int -n: number of rows (points) in the data set to be classified   
* @param int -k: number of clusters to be calculated
* @param float * -X: dataset to be classified
* @param float * -centroid: prototypes of each cluster. 
* @param float * -distance_output[n][k] contains the distance between all elements * in the dataset and all clusters
* return void  
*/
void calc_all_distances(int dim, int n, int k, float *restrict X, float *restrict centroid, float *distance_output) {
    #pragma omp parallel for simd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) // for each point
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) // for each cluster 
            // calculate distance between point and cluster centroid
            distance_output[i*k+j] = calc_distance(dim, &X[i*dim], &centroid[j*dim]);
}


/**
* calc_total_distance calculates the clustering overall distance.  
* @param int -dim: number of columns (variables) in the data set to be classified
* @param int -n: number of rows (points) in the data set to be classified   
* @param int -k: number of clusters to be calculated
* @param float * -X: dataset to be classified
* @param float * -centroid: prototypes of each cluster. 
* @param int * - cluster_assignment_index: current cluster assignment to each point
* @return float overall distance. This is what the algorithm tried to minimize  
*/
float calc_total_distance(int dim, int n, int k, float *restrict X, float *restrict centroids, int *restrict cluster_assignment_index) {
    // NOTE: a point with cluster assignment -1 is ignored
    float tot_D = 0;

    // for every point
    #pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:tot_D)
//BOTTLENECK
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // which cluster is it in?
        int active_cluster = cluster_assignment_index[i];

        // sum distance
        if (active_cluster != -1)
            tot_D += calc_distance(dim, &X[i*dim], &centroids[active_cluster*dim]);
    }

    return tot_D;
}


/**
* choose_all_clusters_from_distances obtains the closest cluster for each point.  
* @param int -dim: number of columns (variables) in the data set to be classified
* @param int -n: number of rows (points) in the data set to be classified   
* @param int -k: number of clusters to be calculated
* @param float * -distance_array[n][k] contains the distance between all elements * in the dataset and all clusters
* @param int* - cluster_assignment_index contains the assigned cluster to each point 
* @return void
*/
void choose_all_clusters_from_distances(int dim, int n, int k, float *restrict distance_array, int *cluster_assignment_index) {
    // for each point
    #pragma omp parallel for simd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int best_index = -1;
        float closest_distance = INFINITY;

        // for each cluster
//  #pragma omp privete(best_index, closest_distance)
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            // distance between point and cluster centroid
            float cur_distance = distance_array[i*k+j];
            if (cur_distance < closest_distance) {
                best_index = j;
                closest_distance = cur_distance;
            }
        }

        // record in array
        cluster_assignment_index[i] = best_index;
    }
}

/**
* calc_cluster_centroids calculates the new prototypes of all clusters 
* @param int -dim: number of columns (variables) in the data set to be classified
* @param int -n: number of rows (points) in the data set to be classified   
* @param int -k: number of clusters to be calculated
* @param float * -X: dataset to be classified
* @param int * - cluster_assigment_index:  
* @param float * -new_cluster_centroid: it is the output with the new cluster prototypes
*/

void calc_cluster_centroids(int dim, int n, int k, float *restrict X, int *restrict cluster_assignment_index, float *new_cluster_centroid) {
    int * cluster_member_count = (int *) calloc (k,sizeof(float));

    // sum all points
    // for every point
    #pragma omp parallel for simd
//BOTTLENECK
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // which cluster is it in?
        int active_cluster = cluster_assignment_index[i];

        // update count of members in that cluster
        ++cluster_member_count[active_cluster];

        // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
            new_cluster_centroid[active_cluster*dim + j] += X[i*dim + j];
    }

// USAR CONCELLATION POINT FOR O LA OTRA FORMA COMENTADA?      
    // now divide each coordinate sum by number of members to find mean/centroid
    // for each cluster
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        if (cluster_member_count[i] == 0) {
            //printf("WARNING: Empty cluster %d! \n", i);
            //break;
            #pragma omp cancel for
        }
        #pragma omp cancellation point for

        // for each dimension
    #pragma omp simd 
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
            new_cluster_centroid[i*dim + j] /= cluster_member_count[i];  /// XXXX will divide by zero here for any empty clusters!
    }
}

/**
* get_cluster_member_count the member of each cluster
* @param int -n: number of rows (points) in the data set to be classified   
* @param int -k: number of clusters to be calculated
* @param int* - cluster_assignment_index contains the assigned cluster to each point 
* @param int * -cluster_member_count: count members of each cluster 
*/
void get_cluster_member_count(int n, int k, int *restrict cluster_assignment_index, int *cluster_member_count) {
    // count members of each cluster    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    #pragma omp atomic update
        ++cluster_member_count[cluster_assignment_index[i]];
}


/**
* Visualize the number of members for all clusters
*/
void cluster_diag(int dim, int n, int k, float *restrict X, int *restrict cluster_assignment_index, float *restrict cluster_centroid) {
    int * cluster_member_count = (int *) calloc (k, sizeof(int));

    get_cluster_member_count(n, k, cluster_assignment_index, cluster_member_count);

    printf("  Final clusters\n");
    #pragma omp parallel for ordered
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) { 
    #pragma omp ordered
        printf("\tcluster %d:  members: %8d, for the centroid (", i, cluster_member_count[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)  
            #pragma omp ordered 
            printf ("%f, ", cluster_centroid[i*dim + j]);
    #pragma omp ordered
        printf (")\n");
    }
}

void copy_assignment_array(int n, int *restrict src, int *tgt) {
    #pragma omp  parallel for simd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        tgt[i] = src[i];
}  


int assignment_change_count(int n, int a[], int b[]) {
    int change_count = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:change_count)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            ++change_count;

    return change_count;
}


/*
* This is C source code for a simple implementation of the popular k-means clustering algorithm. 
* It is based on the implementation in Matlab, which was in turn based on GAF Seber, 
* Multivariate Observations, 1964, and H Spath, Cluster Dissection and Analysis: Theory, FORTRAN Programs, Examples.
* @param int -dim: number of columns (variables) in the data set to be classified (dimension of data)
* @param float * -X: dataset to be classified (pointer to data)
* @param int -n: number of rows (points) in the data set to be classified (number of elements)
* @param int -k: number of clusters to be calculated
* @param float * -cluster_centroid: Initial clusters prototypes or centros (initial cluster centroids)
* @param int iterations -: number of iterations to be performed
* @param int * cluster_assignment_final -: Output classitfication  
*/
void kmeans(int dim, float *X, int n, int k, float *cluster_centroid, int iterations, int *cluster_assignment_final) {
    int floatPointerSize = n * k * sizeof(float);
    int intPointerSize = n * sizeof(int);
    float *dist = (float *) malloc( floatPointerSize );
    int *cluster_assignment_cur = (int *) malloc( intPointerSize );
    int  *cluster_assignment_prev = (int *) malloc( intPointerSize );
    float *point_move_score = (float *) malloc( floatPointerSize );

    if (!dist || !cluster_assignment_cur || !cluster_assignment_prev || !point_move_score)
        fail("Error allocating dist arrays\n");

    // Initial setup. Assignment Step  
    calc_all_distances(dim, n, k, X, cluster_centroid, dist);
    choose_all_clusters_from_distances(dim, n, k, dist, cluster_assignment_cur);
    copy_assignment_array(n, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_assignment_prev);

    //The initial quality is the one obtained from the random election
    float prev_totD = calc_total_distance(dim, n, k, X, cluster_centroid, cluster_assignment_cur);

    int numVariations = 0;
    // UPDATE STEP
    // for (int batch=0; (batch < iterations) && (numVariations <MAX_ITER_NO_IMPR); ++batch) {

   for (int batch = 0; batch < iterations; ++batch) {
        //printf("Batch step: %d \n", batch);
        //cluster_diag(dim, n, k, X, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_centroid);

        // update cluster centroids. Update Step
        calc_cluster_centroids(dim, n, k, X, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_centroid);

        float totD = calc_total_distance(dim, n, k, X, cluster_centroid, cluster_assignment_cur);

        // see if we've failed to improve
        if (totD >= prev_totD){
            // failed to improve - currently solution worse than previous
            // restore old assignments
            copy_assignment_array(n, cluster_assignment_prev, cluster_assignment_cur);

            // recalc centroids
            // calc_cluster_centroids(dim, n, k, X, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_centroid);    
            //printf("\tNegative progress made on this step - iteration completed (%.2f) \n", prev_totD-totD);
            ++numVariations; //To implement no convergence criteria               
        }
        else { // We have made some improvements        
            // save previous step
            copy_assignment_array(n, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_assignment_prev);
            // move all points to nearest cluster
            calc_all_distances(dim, n, k, X, cluster_centroid, dist);
            choose_all_clusters_from_distances(dim, n, k, dist, cluster_assignment_cur);
            //check how many assignments are different  
            //int change_count = assignment_change_count(n, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_assignment_prev);
            //printf("\tIn the batch: %d, has changed: %d element to a different cluster with an improvement of %f \n", batch, change_count, prev_totD-totD);
            //fflush(stdout);
            prev_totD = totD;
        } 
    }

// 
    cluster_diag(dim, n, k, X, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_centroid);

    // write to output array
    copy_assignment_array(n, cluster_assignment_cur, cluster_assignment_final);    

    //Free memory
    free(dist);
    free(cluster_assignment_cur);
    free(cluster_assignment_prev);
    free(point_move_score);
}           



/**
* random_init_centroid chooses random prototypes that belong to the dataset. They are points of the dataset.   
*@param float * -: cluster_centro_if: clustes id choosen
*@param float * -: dataSetMatrix 
*@param int clusters: Number of cluster to be don. 
*@param int rows in number of rows in the dataset; i.e. points
*@param int columns: number of columns. Point's dimension. 
*@return void
*/
void random_init_centroid (float * cluster_centro_id, float * dataSetMatrix, int clusters, int rows, int columns) {
   srand(time(NULL));

   for (int i=0; i<clusters; ++i) {
        int r = rand()%rows; 
        for (int j=0; j<columns;++j) {
            cluster_centro_id[i*columns+j]=dataSetMatrix[r*columns+j];
            //printf ("Los indices son  %d\n", r*columns+j);        
        }       
    }
}   



int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
/**/ 
    if( !omp_get_cancellation() )
    {
        //printf("Cancellations were not enabled, enabling cancellation and rerunning program\n");
        putenv("OMP_CANCELLATION=true");
        execv(argv[0], argv);
    }
    int numHilos = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp master
    numHilos = omp_get_num_threads();
    }
    if (numHilos == 1) {
    //printf("Program is executing sequentially, setting 2 threads and rerunning program\n");
        putenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS=2");
        execv(argv[0], argv);
    }
/**/

    float *cluster_centroid;   // initial cluster centroids. The size is Clusters x rows
    int *clustering_output;  // output
    int rows=0, columns=0, clusters=1;
    int iterations = 1000;
    float * dataSetMatrix=NULL;
    char c, *fileName=NULL;

    //int err=system("clear");

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "v:c:f:i:h")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'v':
            printf("K means algorithm v.1.0\n\n");
        return 0;
        case 'c':
            clusters = atoi(optarg);
            if (clusters < 1) { 
                    printf ("the minimum number of clusters is 1\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
        case 'f':
                fileName = (char *) malloc (strlen(optarg)+1);  
            strcpy(fileName,optarg);
            break;
        case 'i':
                iterations = atoi (optarg);  
                break;
        case 'h':
        case '?':
            printf("Usage:\trun -c number of clusters -f fichero.txt -i number of iterations [-h | -? HELP] \n");
        printf("\t<Params>\n");
        printf("\t\t-v\t\tOutput version information and exit\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //printf ("..............Loading data set...............\n "); 
    // Get file size dataset
    getSizeFile( fileName, &rows, &columns );

    clustering_output = (int *) malloc (rows*sizeof(int));
    // Reserve dynamic memory for dataset matrix
    reserveDynamicMemoryForMatrix( &dataSetMatrix, rows, columns );

    // Set data in the dataset matrix
    setDataInMatrix( dataSetMatrix, fileName, rows, columns );

    //printf ("-------DataSet: \n");
    //printMatrix(dataSetMatrix, rows, columns);

    // printf ("..............Done..............\n "); 
    cluster_centroid = (float *) malloc (clusters*columns*sizeof(float));
    random_init_centroid (cluster_centroid, dataSetMatrix, clusters, rows, columns);   

    //printf (".........Initial Prototypes: ................ \n");
    //printMatrix(cluster_centroid, clusters, columns);

// COMENTAR ESTAS LÍNEA PARA NO MOSTRAR RESULTADOS
    printf ("The number of instance: %d Variables: %d Clusters: %d and Iterations: %d\n", rows, columns,clusters, iterations);
//  printf ("File: %d; \tClusters: %d; \tIterations: %d\n", filename, clusters, iterations);
//    
    double ini = omp_get_wtime();
    kmeans (columns, dataSetMatrix, rows, clusters, cluster_centroid, iterations, clustering_output);  
    double fin = omp_get_wtime();
    printf ("The execution time is %lf seconds\n", fin-ini);

    // Free memory
    free (dataSetMatrix); 
    free (cluster_centroid);
    free (clustering_output); 
}
```

Anyone know why this bottlenecks? And how could I solve them?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT 1:** 

After @Brice changes, I get next errors:

[image: ErrorPict1]
[image: ErrorPict2]

Comment: Parallelization is not a magic bullet.  It does not necessarily make everything faster.  OpenMP is not magic either.  It leaves responsibility on the programmer to correctly account for data dependencies and, to some extent, to protect against data races.

Comment: In any case, you have posted a huge chunk of code.  Our expectation for troubleshooting questions such as this one are that the question will reduce the issue to a [mcve], and present only that.  That helps *both* the asker and potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

1°/ I do not see many opportunities for vectorization, so it is likely that the `simd` construct will not improve performance of the first loop. It could on the second one.

2°/ The loop contains write operations on shared variables `cluster_member_count` and `new_cluster_centroid`, and these should be protected against race conditions with `omp atomic` or `omp critical` pragmas. This will result in the serialization of most of the loop. What you need is to make sure that two threads cannot process points that belong to the same cluster.

There are several options to resolve the issue. One is to get the cluster number first and then decide if it will be processed or not.

```
// make sure the code will compile even if openMP is disabled
#ifdef _OPENMP
   #include <omp.h>
#else
   #define omp_get_num_threads() 1
   #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
#endif

#pragma omp parallel
{
// declare local variables
int active_cluster;
int myThread = omp_get_thread_num();
int nbOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     active_cluster = cluster_assignment_index[i];
     if (active_cluster%nbOfThreads == myThread){

     // update count of members in that cluster
     ++cluster_member_count[active_cluster];

     // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
     #pragma omp simd
     for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
         new_cluster_centroid[active_cluster*dim + j] += X[i*dim + j];
     }// end if
} //end parallel
```

Two issues there:
This may result in the threads being unbalanced, if some clusters are significantly bigger than others. This could be solved by counting cluster members in a first pass, and then decide do some load balancing.
Also, even though each thread now writes data only at locations where noone else will write, the data may still belong to cache lines used by other threads, resulting in [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). For instance, in order increment `cluster_member_count[2]`, a thread need to get it from the memory since cluster_member_count[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) has just been modified by another thread. This is slow.

A better way would be arrange that each thread only writes data to contiguous memory spaces.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
// declare local variables
int active_cluster;
int myThread = omp_get_thread_num();
int nbOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
int process_from=myThread*k/nbOfThreads;
int process_to = (myThread+1==nbOfThreads) ? k : (myThread+1)*k/nbOfThreads;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     active_cluster = cluster_assignment_index[i];
     if (active_cluster>=process_from && active_cluster<process_to ){
     //SAME//
     }
}
```

Finally, a 'map-reduce' approach, while using slighlty more memory, can be convenient there. It consumes more memory d/t local buffers but show how an algorithm may have to be tuned to be parallelized:

```
// add to header
#ifdef _OPENMP
   #include <omp.h>
#else
   #define omp_get_num_threads() 1
   #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
#endif


void calc_cluster_centroids(int dim, int n, int k, float *const X, int *const cluster_assignment_index, float *restrict new_cluster_centroid) {
    int ** cluster_member_count;
    float ** local_cluster_centroid;
    float normFactor;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    //declare variables
    int active_cluster;
    int myThread = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nbOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int number_count;
    float normFactor;

    // allocate memory
    // this is done now as we need to be in the parallel region to know how many threads there are
    // one thread will allocate the arrays of local buffers, the each thread allocates its own local buffers
    #pragma omp single
    {
        cluster_member_count=malloc(nbOfThreads*sizeof(*cluster_member_count));
        local_cluster_centroid=malloc(nbOfThreads*sizeof(*local_cluster_centroid));
    }
    // allocate local buffer for each thread
    // for thread 0, local_cluster_centroid[0] contains new_cluster_centroid
    cluster_member_count[myThread] = calloc(k,sizeof(int));
    if (myThread) local_cluster_centroid[myThread] = calloc(k*dim,sizeof(float));
    else local_cluster_centroid[myThread] = new_cluster_centroid;


    //MAP : loop over points, increment count and accumumlate position in a local buffer
    int *my_member_count=cluster_member_count[myThread];
    float *my_cluster_centroid=local_cluster_centroid[myThread];

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // each thread writes in its own buffer so there is no race condition or cache false sharing

        active_cluster = cluster_assignment_index[i];
        // update count of members in that cluster
        ++my_member_count[active_cluster];

        // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
            my_cluster_centroid[active_cluster*dim + j] += X[i*dim + j];
    }


    // REDUCE : loop over clusters and summ all local buffers
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,64)
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        number_count=cluster_member_count[0][i];
        for (int buff=1 ; buff<nbOfThreads ; ++buff){
            number_count+=cluster_member_count[buff][i];

            // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
            for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
                local_cluster_centroid[0][i*dim + j]+=local_cluster_centroid[buff][i*dim + j];
        }
        normFactor=(number_count) ? 1/(float) number_count : 1.0f ;
        #pragma omp simd
        for (int j = i*dim; j<(i+1)*dim ; ++j)
            cluster_member_count[0][j]*=normFactor;
    }

    // free memory
    free(cluster_member_count[myThread]);
    if (myThread) free(local_cluster_centroid[myThread]);

    }//end parallel
    //once each thread has freeed its own buffer, let the master free the array of buffers
    free(cluster_member_count);
    free(local_cluster_centroid);

}//end function
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you! As soon as I get home, I'll try it and tell you

Comment: I have ran it. But I did not achieve get it work. I get: `Aborted ('core' generated)` if I comment `free` clauses. If `free` clauses are not commented I get next error: `Error in './run': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fdd60000078`.  I have tryed your code copying your `calc_cluster_centroids` instead of mine and declaring into header file your header code

Comment: More specific. I get this three errors: 
)`*** Error in './run': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000117f3a0 ***)`
)`*** Error in './run': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd110000078 ***)`
)`Aborted ('core' generated)`

And as output I get so much lines like:
`7fd1210e4000-7fd1210e5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0`
`7fd1210e5000-7fd1218e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0`
`7fd1218e5000-7fd1218e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0`
...

Comment: One barrier was missing, so that the first thread to complete would get into the final `single` part and `free(cluster_member_count)`, while threads completing later would attempt to `free(cluster_member_count[myThread])`. Either a barrier should be added, or the last part moved outside of the parallel region (the end of the parallel region being an implicit barrier). Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: I have updated code with your modifications, but I continue giving same error. I have updated my own question for you can see the error, okay?

Comment: I have been for days trying to make your code working, but I couldn't get it. Can you take a look, please? I have tryed many ways, I think the problem is not in free due to commenting this lines I get other error `run: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion '(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.`. Also I tryed mallocing out of parallel region, etc... and I did not achieve it.